# How to forward fill based on previous 10 days (not last 10 rows ) if any value available in previous 10 days in pySpark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql, aws-databricks

I want to forward fill if there is some value available in past 10 days based on today's date.
I can't use below code for cases when there is missing date for some id.

```
df.withColumn('fill_fwd',F.last("columnToFill", True).over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy('date').rowsBetween(-10, 0))
```

is there any other way? I also don't want to create rows for missing date if possible.